# I cannot return a value. ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Tags: mysql, function

I'm writting a function in MySQL which has to check that the values from PHP form exists in Database.

I have tried to return a VARCHAR variable from my function which is set in SELECT... CASE statement by a CONCAT function, but still i see an error.

```
CREATE FUNCTION checkNewUser(login VARCHAR(30),password VARCHAR(255),email VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
    set @result = "";
    SELECT user_login,user_password,user_email,
    CASE
        WHEN user_login = login THEN @result = CONCAT(@result," This login is not avaible!")
        WHEN user_password = password THEN @result = CONCAT(@result," This password is not avaible!")
        WHEN user_email = email THEN @result = CONCAT(@result," This email is not avaible!")
        ELSE  @result = NULL
    END
    FROM users;
    RETURN @result;
END//
```

I want to return an information, which value from form is wrong. But i still see an error: ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Comment: If you want to clarify the question, use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57660416/edit) link.

Comment: You need to use `SELECT ... INTO variable` in a function, otherwise it tries to return the results of the `SELECT`.

Comment: Also, assignments inside a `SELECT` query need to use `:=`, `=` is comparison.

Comment: You need a `WHERE` clause in the query, otherwise you're overwriting `@result` on each row, and it will just contain the value from the last row of the table.